# storing message titles

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I currently have two tables that create my messaging system: The first is titled

```
Messages
```

and looks like this:

```
messageid| seq | created_on| created_by| body 

1           1      mon      joey       this is a new message w/ title
2           1      mon      joey1      this is a new message w/ title
3           2      tuesday  mikey      this is a reply to message 1 or 2 w/o title
4           3      tuesday  joey       this is a reply to message 3 w/o title
5           1      wednesdaymikey      this is a new message w/ title
```

And the second is irrelevant but is called message_recips and contains who each message is sent to.

My current dilemma is that I am trying to add titles to the messages, but only to new messages (with sequence '1'), and I am wondering how to store these. I do not know much about database design.

From my data table example, you can see that not all messages will have a title. To me, it would seem silly to have a bunch of blank spaces in the table. I assume null spaces still take up some space.

I could see adding a relational table that stores the titles, but to me it also seems painful/silly to have to query ANOTHER table when some of my message queries are already very complex (in my opinion) and sometimes query 3 tables in one go. But again, I am new to this, and this very well may be standard procedure in database design.

Sincere thanks for any help... it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `NULL`, that is what it is there for.

Comment: If you want a better answer you should also probably ask this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: cool, thanks, didn't know about that branch of SO.

Comment: Empty `VARCHAR()` columns don't take up much space. Just add the new column to the table.